# How to return an array as an API resource in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I want (for project reason), to create an array in a class controller and pass it to a resource. 
Consider in my controller class this method:

```
public function getExample(){
  $attribute=array('otherInfo'=>'info');

  return new ExampleResource($attribute);
}
```

and I in my class I would write sominthing like ExampleResource with:

```
public function toArray($request){
return[
'info' => $this->info
];

}
```

How I can convert the  value $attribute to perform this operation `return new ExampleResource($attribute);` ?

Please do not suggest me to insert the field info in the model, this attribute can came from only from the external, from the controller and do not belong to the model in database.

```
class ExampleResource extends Resource
{
    private $info;
    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
     public function __construct($info)
     {
         $this->$info = $info;
     }


    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return[
          'info'=>$this->$info,
          'id' => $this->id
          ];
          }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is quiet confusing. You want an array to `return new ExampleResource($attribute);`? It almost sounds like youre trying to create a model factory?

Answer (score 8):

Add constructor to the resource class:

```
public function __construct($resource, $attribute)
{
    $this->resource = $resource;
    $this->attribute = $attribute;
}
```

Then in `toArray()`:

```
return [
    'info' => $this->attribute,
    'created' => $this->created_at
];
```

And use it:

```
return new ExampleResource(Model::find($id), $attribute);
```

Comment: @user8958651 I've tested this code before posting, I've used array too. Please tell me what line exactly throws an error? Also, please show the exact code you're trying to use now.

Comment: As you can see in the edit file the error is in the constructor: $this->$info= $info;

Comment: @user8958651 change `$this->$info = $info;` to `$this->info = $info;` and do the same in the `toArray()`. I've just copy-pasted `$attribute` and didn't remove the `$` sign.

Comment: with $this->info=$info into costructor, and with 'info'=>$this->info into toArray , the execution return  the error   "Trying to get property of non-object" on the method of     public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->resource->{$key};
    }  in the library Http\Resources\DelegatesToResource.php

Comment: @user8958651 please update code in the question with current one.

Comment: OK, it works only if in the toArray method I put the info attribute, but in my real case, as you can see now, i have in the toArray another attribute that came from the model of the resource  'id' => $this->id, with this it stop to work. I wnat that toArray work with both the attribute (one from the resource I mean id, and another from external that came from the constructor I mean info

Comment: @user8958651 if you want to pass object and attribute, you need to change constructor a bit. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks again, what means  $resource in the construct? In my situation is ExampleResource the resource in wich i want to add the attribute "info"

Comment: @user8958651 the is model object you pass into the resource class. You can look into the source code of the `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource` class if you want to understand how exactly this works.

Answer (score 0):

Resources are intended to be used to easily transform your models into JSON.

Take a look at this example:

```
use App\User;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;

Route::get('/user', function () {
    return new UserResource(User::find(1));
});
```

You just want to return an array of data so you should just return the array, it will be automatically turned into JSON:

```
Route::get('/info', function () {
    return ['info' => 'info ...'];
});
```

For more informations check the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources)

Comment: what if I want to get the array without return it first ?